# How to deployee cheatsheet in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have developed a simple cheat sheet in eclipse.
Now I want to install that cheat sheet plugin in eclipse itself

Can anyone help me how to do that???

Answer (score 0):

If you have developed a cheat sheet plugin as described in the [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_cheatsheet.htm), with the right extension point like:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.cheatSheetContent">
    <cheatsheet
        name="%cheatsheet.helloworld.name"
        contentFile="$nl$/cheatsheets/HelloWorld.xml"
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.helloworld">
        <description>%cheatsheet.helloworld.desc</description>
    </cheatsheet>
```

, then you can launch and test your plugin [in another instance of Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_my_plug-in_in_another_instance_of_Eclipse%3F).

```
Run > Run As > Run-time Workbench
```

This is called self-hosting

---

Once tested, you need to deploy it in your own Eclipse instance. See [PDE UI FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDE/User_Guide#PDE_UI)

> To test code in the host, you need to export and install into the running Eclipse instance.
>
> To export plug-ins and features and install them into the host Eclipse do the following:
>
> 1. Develop your plug-ins and features in the workspace
> 2. Open the export wizard, either `File > Export... > Plug-in Development > Deployable plug-ins and fragments` or `File > Export... > Plug-in Development > Deployable features`
> 3. Select your plug-ins or features to export and install
> 4. Select the last option on the Destination tab Install into host. Repository. Then choose a directory to create the repository in
> 5. Hit Finish. The export operation will run followed by the installation operation.
> 6. If the operations completed successfully, you will be prompted to restart. Choose to restart now
>
> Your plug-ins will be installed and running after the restart.
>   You can see what has been installed using the Installation Details button on the About Dialog (available by going to `Help > About Eclipse SDK`)

Comment: yes i have done that..now i want to install my cheatsheet in eclipse own instance (not in another instance)...like in eclipse Help->CheatSheet it will open a window to select cheatsheet..i want my cheatsheet there..in same plugin instance not in another...another is only for testing purpose and i have tested it.,,,,plz tell me how to do that??

Comment: @Rahul: I have completed my answer to include this deployment step.